# Whats the best way to secure a loose flooring joist where mortar has crumbled over the decades?

Tags: subfloor, joists, mortar

My kitchen floor sits on joints that are mostly OK. One wobbles though as I walk over it near a wall. It moves 0.5cm (0.25"). I lifted a floor board and had a look. You can see the crumbled mortar here:

[image: joist on crumbling mortar]

**Question: Do I replace the mortar after jacking up the joist a little?  Or do I get a hardwood wedge and tap it in - as the joist goes out the other side and supports a narrow hallway?**

The house was built in 1973 in the UK, if that's important. Lastly, it is my poor photography that makes the joists look non-vertical, not poor construction.

Here's the adjacent one that is fine for now:

[image: joist on mortar that is OK]

The sub floor area is a crawl space - but only just - not for anyone with a belly. The black is a bitcuhmen seal over the earth underneath.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

1. support joist
2. rake out old loose motar
3. fill with new mortar - force to full depth
4. allow to cure
5. remove support

Worked fine for me.

Comment: I agree, though a properly-fitted pressure-treated wooden shim would do as well as mortar. Ideally it has very little taper, providing a large bearing surface. Drive it in until reasonably snug and be done.

Comment: So, you need at least one or two more, for the sides. I took the time to reset the odd loose brick as well.

Comment: Wouldn't hurt, but not critical. A joist under load isn't going anywhere.

Comment: Helped stop the squeaking of the floor once finished. Worth doing though as the floor came up nice once waxed.

Comment: I'd buy standard mortar in the just-add-water mixing tubs, right, as this joist isn't supporting a ton. And for shims, pressure-treated soft/white wood is OK? If I'm trimming it do I lose the pn'tressure-treated aspect?  How about hard-wood? The house never ever gets rising water or damp under there, so not having it pressure treated could be OK.